# How do I results to an array?

Tags: swift, closures, completionhandler

Parse operation was performed with JSON. I created the completion. And I get string value ​​from here. I pass these strings to an initializer. How do I add this string to an array?

My Model Class:

```
class ExamplesModel {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Completion phase:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
let examplesModel = ExamplesModel(name: name)
completion(.Success(examplesModel))
}
```

Defined completion variables:

```
enum Result<T> {
case Success(T)

case Error(String)
}
```

and I want to append the string to the array:

```
class ViewController: ... {
var exampleArray = [String]()
...
..
.
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
...
..
.
self.exampleFunc(...some-variables...) { (result) in
//what should I write here?
}
}
```

Comment: What String are you referring to?

Comment: The "name" string.

Comment: Add the definition of exampleFunc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `Switch` statement in the `completionHandler` on the obtained `result`. For `case Success`, get the `name` from `model` and `append` it to the `names` `array` like so,

```
var names = [String]()

self.exampleFunc(chosenLatitude: "", chosenLongitude: "") { (result) in
    switch result {
    case let .Success(model):
        self.names.append(model.name)

    case let .Error(error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Create `names` outside the scope of the method where you're calling `exampleFunc`, for example: as a `class` `property`.

Comment: Thank you for answers. I solved the problem with your help.

Comment: Great. Do accept(tick on left) the answer if it helped. Happy coding..